# Pasar 2 o mas variables en php

Tags: php, mysqli

feliz viernes y feliz fin de semana!

Tengo un par de problemitas, uno se podría resolver si paso al menos dos variables a la pagina siguiente.
**una sola** funciona bien

```
link = '098usredit.php?idusr=' . $row098['98idusr'];
```

De puro ambiciosa quise pasar 3 pero me conformo con dos, esto está dentro del php

```
$link = '098usredit.php?idusr=' . $row098['98idusr']'&nomb=' . $row098['98nomb']'&gr=' . $row098['gr'] ; //asi no funciona pero creo que es porque no sé formar la oración GARCIA A MARZO.
     echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $row098['98idusr'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td aling='left'>" . $row098['98nomb'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align='left'>" . $row098['gr'] .  "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><a href=\"$link\" target= _self ><img src='img/001-lapiz2.png' width='16' height='16' alt=''/></a></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'></td>";
```

***mismo archivo otro tema*** Pagina siguiente 098usredit.php

Por una parte si puedo pasar iduser (ya puedo) pero tambien el nomb me evitaría hacer una consulta innecesaria en esta pagina con lo que sólo serían 2 en vez de 3 como ahora. El problema está en que para obtener el nuevo grupo del usuario utilizo un select/option que funciona perfecto en otras paginas pero en esta no queda registrado y no lo incorpora al UPDATE Transcribo el código básico, pero no me reten. 
Ya tengo el iduser o id o 98idusr y elijo en el select/option el grupo nuevo

FORMULARIO

```
<select name="grupo" required id="grupo" form="f098" title="grupo" >            <option value=""></option>
<?php $sql098b="select idgr, gr from $t98g"; 
$r098b=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql098b); 
while($rw098b=mysqli_fetch_array($r098b)) { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $rw098b['idgr']; ?>"><?php echo $rw098b['gr']; ?></option>
    <?php } $grupo = $rw098b['idgr']; ?>
</select>
```

NO LO TOMA ARROJA ESTE **ERROR: No es posible ejecutar UPDATE 98usr SET 98grupo = '' WHERE 98idusr='31'. Incorrect integer value: '' for column '98grupo' at row 1**

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    // verificar que el boton SUBMIT fue presionado
if(isset($_POST['bt-098']))
{
require_once '990conn.php';
// seleccionar la variable que se va a actualizar grupo = 98grupo también un número definida en la selecion 
$sql098 = "UPDATE 98gr SET 98grupo = '$grupo' WHERE 98idusr='$idusr'"; 
if($mysqli->query($sql098) === true){
    echo "El grupo fue cambiado.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: No es posible ejecutar $sql098. " . $mysqli->error;
} } }
// Close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

En definitiva, veo que el select no queda registrado como valor a pasar y eso me frustra mucho. Talueguito.

Comment: En qué parte del código estás asignando un valor a tu variable `$grupo`?

Comment: está en la última fila del select antes de cerrarlo  $grupo = $rw098b['idgr'];

Comment: La asignación `$grupo = $rw098b['idgr'];` no está dentro del `while` en el cual recorres los resultados, por tanto, no te está asignado en `$grupo` el valor de la columna `idgr`.

Comment: Lo puse dentro y lo cambia, no por lo que yo elija pero lo cambia, vamos todavía!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A. Si el `UPDATE` lo intentas desde la misma página

Si el `UPDATE`quieres lanzarlo desde la misma página, sin presionar ningún botón del formulario, estás asignando `$grupo` fuera del `while`... hay que ponerse una lupa para verlo en medio de tu código.

Fíjate lo bonito que es un código organizado, ves los errores de una vez:

```
<select name="grupo" required id="grupo" form="f098" title="grupo" >
        <option value=""></option>
<?php 
    $sql098b="select idgr, gr from $t98g"; 
    $r098b=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql098b); 
    while($rw098b=mysqli_fetch_array($r098b)) { 
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rw098b['idgr']; ?>"><?php echo $rw098b['gr']; ?></option>
<?php 
        $grupo = $rw098b['idgr'];  //Esto estaba fuera del recorrido de resultados
    }
?>
</select>
```

---

### B. Si el `UPDATE` se lanza al enviar un formulario

Si el `UPDATE` es lanzado al enviar un formulario, entonces debes recuperar el valor del grupo así:

```
$grupo=$_POST["grupo"];
```

---

### C. En cuanto a tu consulta `UPDATE`:

```
$sql098 = "UPDATE 98gr SET 98grupo = '$grupo' WHERE 98idusr='$idusr'";
```

Ten en cuenta que si cualquiera de los valores es numérico, debes quitar las comillas simples que rodean a la variable:

Ejemplo, suponiendo que `98grupo` es del tipo numérico en la base de datos:

```
$sql098 = "UPDATE 98gr SET 98grupo = $grupo WHERE 98idusr='$idusr'";
```

Lo mismo, si `98idusr` fuese numérico, debes quitar las comillas simples.

---

PD: Ya no te *reto* más a usar consultas preparadas, pero siempre pongo la nota de que este código es peligroso y no me hago responsable de los daños.

Comment: Don Cedano es usted un genio. Sólo por hacerme muy feliz (no te voy a pedir que te cases conmigo yo ya estoy  casada)

<?php  $grupo = $rw098b['idgr'];
toma por defecto el último valor de la tabla, SIEMPRE, no el que yo elijo desde la lista desplegable? Hay forma de corregir eso????

Comment: @SilviaGaviotaGarcia no aceptaría tal propuesta por motivos obvios... Está dicho con claridad en mi perfil. Con respecto a lo que nos atañe, ya está respondido en la parte **B.**. Para recuperar el valor del `option` seleccionado debes enviar ese elemento de alguna manera al servidor y recuperarlo mediante `POST` o `GET`. Eso se suele hacer vía Ajax, de ese modo no tienes que recargar la página.